# How to feature-detect browsers that restrict scroll events?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Many mobile browsers (iOS Safari [until v8](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/), iOS Chrome, and I think some Android browsers) don't fire multiple scroll events while the page is scrolling - instead they just fire a single scroll event when the movement comes to a stop.

Is there any way to feature-detect this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

A good article that breaks this behaviour down can be seen [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/) for the uninformed.

As for your question, potentially you could "feature-detect" it by waiting to see if there's a `scroll` event fired after a `touchmove` event? It's not a perfect solution but it would work after the user first scrolls. That said, touch events are [still a little quirky themselves](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/).

That said, you may need to find an alternative solution to whatever the problem is that you're trying to solve given the behavioural quirks across all the different mobile browsers--scroll behaviour isn't very well defined in mobile browsers as yet, and it'll get to be very hard to deal with performantly.